# generating a new image using a transformer class java

Tags: java

I am using a transformer class in order to generate a new image with modified pixels. Basically I am iterating over each pixel in the original image, then applying the given transformation (ex. color inversion, contrast, etc.) in order to generate a new picture. I'm not really sure how to approach this problem...this is what I have so far.

```
public static NewPicture transform(NewPicture p, Transformer t) {
int w = p.getWidth();
int h = p.getHeight();

Pixel[][] src = getBitmap();
Pixel[][] tgt = new Pixel[w][h];

for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
    // Not sure what to do after this nested for loop
```

NewPicture is simply an image represented by a 2D array of Pixels. The interface for my Pixel transformer is

```
public interface Transformer {
  public Pixel transformPixel (pixel p);
}
```

It simply creates a new Pixel based on the given RGB components of the input, but does not modify the pixel.

I would appreciate any guidance as to how to approach this problem. Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I just do not know what to do after my nested for loop. What I basically need to do it apply the transforming operation to the original image in order to produce a new one...but I'm not sure how I would do this after the nested for loop.

Comment: *"I just do not know.."*  ..how to form a requirement into a question.

Comment: What is a `NewPicture` object?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`RGBImageFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/RGBImageFilter.html) class, that does exactly what you want.